# How to remove a CALayer's mask?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

Hi guys so this is my first question on SO, this has been boggling me for hours. Here is my code.

.m

```
- (IBAction)changeMask:(id)sender {
if (!mask) {

    [wallpaperImageView.layer setMask:captionTextField.layer];

    NSLog(@"%@",captionTextField.layer);
    mask = YES;
}
else {

    wallpaperImageView.layer.mask = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",captionTextField);
    mask = NO;
}


}
```

Every time `wallpaperImageView.layer.mask = nil;` is called, `captionTextField.layer` gets deallocated. I am using ARC in my project. I assigned captionTextField with `@property (nonatomic, strong)` I used NSZombies and got `*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x85b5e20`

How do I let the CALayer not get deallocated?

Comment: Okay, I read about pointers and realized that wallpaperImageView.layer.mask is pointing to 0x85b5e20 and when i make it nil captionTextField.layer is nil too…. Any workarounds to my code above?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information. Who owns your captionTextField?

Post the code that shows how you create your captionTextField, and where you store it. You need to save a strong reference to it somewhere (strong instance variable or property) or it will indeed get released as soon as nobody holds onto it.

It does not make sense that setting your wallpaperImageView's layer's mask to nil is causing your captionTextField to be released, unless you create your captionTextField and don't keep a strong reference to it.